# Rich Text Editor image tool not showing up

Tags: rte

I'm trying to figure out why the Tool 'Image' function under the RTE module isn't showing up on our front end dashboard. I can easily remove/add other Tools such as 'Underline' or 'Link' and the changes do take place. However, 'Image' will not. I do have it enabled. Am I missing something? Hopefully the images help show you where I am. I appreciate any insight. Thank you.

[image: RTE Module page, back end]

[image: Dashboard RTE, front end]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Found Answer:** Check out the rte.image.php file, line 32. `'cp_only' => 'n'`

It was originally set to 'y'. Now to get it functioning!

Hopefully this helps others.

Comment: Thanks so much for this! I was going crazy trying to figure why the image tool was not displaying in my Channel Form. Turns out 'cp_only' => 'n' is documented in http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/rte_tools.html. Why would anybody look there unless they want to develop their own RTE tools? Frustrating.

Comment: Glad this was able to help someone! We finally gave up on this RTE we were using for our created front end. It just wouldn't function after exhausting and troubleshooting every idea.